# Реинициализация DOM элементов jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

Добрый день, при динамическом добавлении элементов, не получается их инициализировать, чтобы обработчик срабатывал.
Вот html:

```
<h3>Для устройств:</h3>
<div class="device">
    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Брэнд</option>
        </select><select>
        <option>Модель</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#remove" class="remove">х</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#add" class="add">Добавить еще одно устройство</a>
```

И js:

```
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    $('.device').append('<div><select><option>Брэнд</option></select><select><option>Модель</option></select> <a href="#remove" class="remove">х</a></div>');
});

$('.remove').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Пример на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/8WqMP/1/)

Comment: Ни с .live(), .delegate(), .on() ничего не вышло, не пойму что не так делаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так выйдет:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    /* some js */
});
```

Про live, delegate, bind забудьте. Ваш код: http://jsfiddle.net/8WqMP/2/

Comment: Поторопился я с вопросом, сам разобрался. Но все равно спасибо.